# Trouble understand a step in the proof that $l^p$ is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm reading through a proof, attached here. I didn't include the whole proof. The last step is the one I'm confused about. Shouldn't there be more of a justication for taking $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ inside the the sum? More precisely, how do they go from 
$$\sum_{j=1}^k |\xi_j^{(m)} - \xi_j^{(n)}|^p < \varepsilon^p $$
to
$$\sum_{j=1}^k |\xi_j^{(m)} - \xi_j|^p < \varepsilon^p$$
?

I know that $\xi_j^{(m)} \to \xi_j$ as $m \to \infty$, but I don't see how this allows us to just bring inside the sum.

Here is the start of the proof:
[image]

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n+b_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n$ if all limits exists.. As it is finite sum we can take limit

Comment: See dear old Baby Rudin 3.3 or equivalent statements in any introductory real analysis book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of a finite sum is the finite sum of the limits, and the limit of an absolute value is the absolute value of the limit.

Comment: What about the $p$th power?

Comment: The same: the limit goes inside because $x\mapsto |x|^p$ is continuous.

Comment: Why does the $<$ become a $\le$ ?

Comment: If you have a convergent sequence $x_n$ such that $|x_n|<1$ for all $n$, then the limit, say $x$, satisfies $|x|\le1$. Take for example $1-(1/n)$.